# Comparar dos bases de datos postgreSQL

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Necesito comparar dos bases de datos postgresql, tengo una base de datos en desarrollo y debo pasarla a producción pero necesito ver todos los cambios que se han realizado. he utilizado apgdiff pero no se muestra el resultado esperado.

estoy ejecutando el cmd de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al momento de ejecutarlo se presenta lo siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Espero te ayude asi lo uso yo te dejo un ejemplo

estructura de base de datos en producción:

```
 pg_dump --host localhost --port 5432 -U postgres  --format plain --schema-only  -f  tmp/productionv1.sql dell
```

estructura de base de datos en desarrollo:

```
pg_dump --host localhost --port 5432 -U postgres  --format plain --schema-only  -f  tmp/developer2.sql dell
```

Cuando ya tengas las bases de datos exportadas se le dice a apgdiff que detecte los cambios realizados para aplicarlos en producción, ejemplo:

```
java -jar apgdiff-2.4.jar productionv1.sql developer2.sql > cambios.sql
```

como sabes apgdiff esta hecho en java una vez lo ejecutes tendrias el archivo cambios.sql con los cambios donde solo seria agregarlos donde quieras

Comment: Hola Oscar, muchas gracias por la respuesta, he colocado el comando dentro del cmd, pero al intentar hacer esto en mi máquina se me presenta el siguiente mensaje: 
pg_dump: server version: 9.6.1; pg_dump version: 9.5.5
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch

y al intentar hacerle remotamente en otra máquina se me presenta el siguiente mensaje:
pg_dump: [archiver] no se pudo abrir el archivo de salida <<tmp/base.sql>>: No such file or directory

Comment: umm al parecer tienes un problema de versiones el comando pg_dump utilizado para crear el archivo exportado es más antiguo que la versión de Postgres de la base de datos de destino te dejo esta pagina como guia https://blndxp.wordpress.com/2016/03/09/posgresql-pg_dump-client-and-server-versions-mismatch/

Comment: Sabes ya le actualicé a mi máquina, pero se me presenta el mensaje de: no se pude abrir el archivo de salida. Esa es la única forma de crear el archivo sql de la base? Gracias.

Comment: en que sistema opertativo estas trabajando linux ? si es asi revisa el tema de permisos .... pues que yo conozca si la otra opcion es comparando los archivos con un programa llamado meld y las diferencias agregarlas a mano

Comment: Estoy trabajando en windows

Comment: He generado el archivo .sql de mi base de datos mediante el siguiente comando: 
  
    pg_dump -U username-W -h domain data_base_name > data_base_name.sql
http://viviryaprenderweb.com/hacer-un-dump-completo-y-como-importarlo-en-postgres/


una vez generados los dos archivos .sql necesarios he ejecutado el comando de apgdiff y eso me ha funcionado correctamente. Gracias @Oscar.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado no olvides de aceptar la respuesta

Comment: D una pregunta, por qué puede ser que en el documento sql resultante se encuentra el create de unas tablas que están ya en las dos bases?

Comment: @CarmenA. puede haber diferencias no tan visibles en la definición de las tablas como el collate, el orden de las columnas, etc.